# How to expect input from redirection and user input

Tags: c++, file, stdin, cin, io-redirection

So I'm trying to either

a) allow user to input a string until they type exit

or

b) redirect file from standard input(`a.out < test.txt`) until at end of file and then terminate

My attempt at the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string input = "";
    while(true){
       cout << "Enter string: ";
       while(getline(cin, input)){
       if(input == "exit" || cin.eof()) goto end;
       cout << input << "\n";
       cout << "Enter string: ";                       
     }

    }
    end:
    return 0;



}
```

This causes an issue with redirection, when I use command `a.out < test.txt` I get an infinite loop (where test.txt contains one line "hello")

User input seems to work fine

I'm using getline because in the actual program I need to read a file line by line and then manipulate the line before moving on to the next line of the file

**EDIT:** My question is, how do I terminate this loop accounting for both user input and redirection?

Comment: Your code is working for me https://ideone.com/pj0xID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string input = "";
  while(cin && cout<<"Enter string: " && getline(cin, input)){
    //check both cout and cin are OK with the side effect of
    // writing "Enter string" and reading a line

    if(input == "exit") return 0; //no need for a goto
    cout << input << "\n";
  }
  if(cin.eof()) return 0; //ended because of EOF
  return 1; //otherwise, the loop must have broken because of an error
}
```

Keep it simple. You don't need the outer loop and the `cin.eof()` will never be true inside the while block because if `cin.eof()` is true, then the `getline` expression which returns `cin` which converts to bool would convert to false, thereby ending the loop.

The loop ends if `cin` encounters the EOF or an error.

Answer (score 1):

well, in first case use of goto is not recommended, you can use boolean data type  to achieve your goal:

```
int main(){
bool flag = true;

string input = "";
while(flag){
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    while(getline(cin, input)){
        if(input == "exit" || cin.eof()) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
        cout << input << "\n";
        cout << "Enter string: ";
    }

  }


 return 0;
}
```